# Compare all strings content in column(Series)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, series

I have got Pandas column with 50000 rows and at the beginning it looks like this (every line is a separate row):

```
'JavaScript, Python, Ruby'
 'Java, PHP, Python'
 'Matlab, Python, R'
 ''
 'Matlab, Python'
 'C#, JavaScript'
 'Objective-C, Swift'
 'R, SQL'
 'C, C++, Java'
 'Java, JavaScript, Ruby'
 'C, C++'
 'JavaScript, VB.NET'
 'C, JavaScript'
 'Perl, Python'
 'C#, JavaScript, SQL'
 'Java'
 'PHP, SQL'
 'Java, Scala'
 'Java, JavaScript, Objective-C'
 'JavaScript, Python'
 'C#, Java'
 'JavaScript'
 'C'
 'C#, JavaScript, Matlab'
 'C#, Java, JavaScript'
```

I get about 900 unique results, but for example `'C#, Java, JavaScript'` and `'C#, JavaScript, Java'` are the same for me (order doesn't matter).

I was trying to simplify this and I wrote code which doesn't work:

```
def String_compare(x):
    for i in range(0, len(df) - 1):        
        while i < (len(df) - 1):
            ## the same lenght and content
            if (set(x[i]) == set(x[i+1])):
                ## change content of the next row from the previous one
                x[i+1] == x[i]
        
## replace() was used to avoid problem with NaN values
df['ITLanguages'] = df['ITLanguages'].replace(np.nan, '?').map(lambda x: String_compare(x))
```

How to compare all values in one column and if they have the same length and content (names of programming language), change it to one version (for example: 'a, b, c', 'a, c, b' and 'b, a, c' are the same and I choose 'a, b, c' version for them all).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that there might be a more effective way to solve whatever problem this solution is intended to solve (hopefully one that's vectorized), but one approach might be to sort the words in each string so that any two strings with equivalent sets of words will be in the same order anyway.

```py
series = series.map(lambda s: ', '.join(sorted(w.strip() for w in s.split(',')))).str.strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you ordered them (sorted the words and removed duplicates(if any exist)) they would all end up the same...

**Input:**

```
'JavaScript,   Ruby , Python'
'JavaScript,   Python , Ruby'
'Python,    Ruby, JavaScript'
 'Matlab, Matlab, Matlab'
 'Java, PHP, Python'
 'Matlab, Python'
 'C#, JavaScript'
 'Swift, Objective-C, Swift'
 'R, SQL'
```

**Code:**

```
def sortNames(x):
    names = x.replace("'", "")
    names = names.replace(",", "")
    names = names.split()
    names = sorted(names)
    names = set(names)
    names = list(filter(None, names))
    names = ', '.join(names)
    return names

df['ProgNames'] = df['ProgNames'].apply(lambda x: sortNames(x))
```

**Output:**

```
    ProgNames
0   Ruby, Python, JavaScript
1   Ruby, Python, JavaScript
2   Ruby, Python, JavaScript
3   Matlab
4   Python, PHP, Java
5   Python, Matlab
6   C#, JavaScript
7   Swift, Objective-C
8   R, SQL
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed all the single quotes from your data first, and then my idea is the same as the others.

```py
from io import StringIO

data = """
JavaScript, Python, Ruby
Java, PHP, Python
PHP, Java, Python
Matlab, Python, R

Matlab, Python
C#, JavaScript
Objective-C, Swift
R, SQL
C, C++, Java
Java, JavaScript, Ruby
C, C++
JavaScript, VB.NET
C, JavaScript
Perl, Python
C#, JavaScript, SQL
Java
PHP, SQL
Java, Scala
Java, JavaScript, Objective-C
JavaScript, Python
C#, Java
JavaScript
C
C#, JavaScript, Matlab
C#, Java, JavaScript
"""

def f(x):
    y = sorted([i.strip() for i in x.strip("'").split(',')])
    return ",".join(y)


s = StringIO(data)
df = pd.read_csv(s, header=None, delimiter="\n")
df[0] = df[0].map(f)
print(df)
```

```
                              0
0        JavaScript,Python,Ruby
1               Java,PHP,Python
2               Java,PHP,Python
3               Matlab,Python,R
4                 Matlab,Python
5                 C#,JavaScript
6             Objective-C,Swift
7                         R,SQL
8                    C,C++,Java
9          Java,JavaScript,Ruby
10                        C,C++
11            JavaScript,VB.NET
12                 C,JavaScript
13                  Perl,Python
14            C#,JavaScript,SQL
15                         Java
16                      PHP,SQL
17                   Java,Scala
18  Java,JavaScript,Objective-C
19            JavaScript,Python
20                      C#,Java
21                   JavaScript
22                            C
23         C#,JavaScript,Matlab
24           C#,Java,JavaScript
```

Comment: I put these strings line by line only here, but as I said before this is a Pandas Series (every line is separate row), so what is the point of using '\n'?

Comment: You can ignore that, as it's only used for splitting the `StringIO` object as I didn't put your data in a separate file.